# Using requests function in python to submit data to a website and call back a response

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to use the requests function in python to post the text content of a text file to a website, submit the text for analysis on said website, and pull the results back in to python. I have read through a number of responses here and on other websites, but have not yet figured out how to correctly modify the code to a new website.

I'm familiar with beautiful soup so pulling in webpage content and removing HTML isn't an issue, its the submitting the data that I don't understand.

My code currently is:

```
import requests

fileName = "texttoAnalyze.txt"        
fileHandle = open(fileName, 'rU');
url_text = fileHandle.read()

url = "http://www.webpagefx.com/tools/read-able/"
payload = {'value':url_text}
r = requests.post(url, payload)
print r.text
```

This code comes back with the html of the website, but hasn't recognized the fact that I'm trying to a submit a form.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks so much.

Comment: `url = "http://www.webpagefx.com/tools/read-able/"` is a web link which redirects us to a webpage, simply posting some data won't get you the required results, you need to dig down the API calls that webpage is making to process your request (Learn using Inspect Element feature in all major browsers) or you may use Headless web surfing with the `Selenium` module of python

Comment: @JonClements, the second arg to post is data

Comment: @Padraic You're right - maybe I'm thinking of something else or a different use-case then :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the same request the website is sending, usually you can get these with web debugging tools (like chrome/firefox developer tools).

In this case the url the request is being sent to is: `http://www.webpagefx.com/tools/read-able/check.php`

With the following params: `tab=Test+by+Direct+Link&directInput=SOME_RANDOM_TEXT`

So your code should look like this:

```
url = "http://www.webpagefx.com/tools/read-able/check.php"
payload = {'directInput':url_text, 'tab': 'Test by Direct Link'}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
print r.text
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are two post parameters, *tab* and *directInput*:

```
import requests

post = "http://www.webpagefx.com/tools/read-able/check.php"
with open("in.txt") as f:
    data = {"tab":"Test by Direct Link",
            "directInput":f.read()}
    r = requests.post(post, data=data)
    print(r.content)
```